# python generators for concurrency

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, generator

I am following slides from Python's guru David Beazley. It states "Generators are also used for concurrency. Here is an example:

```
from collections import deque

def countdown(n):
    while n > 0:
        print("T-minus", n)
        yield
        n -=1

def countup(n):
    x = 0
    while x > n:
        print("Up we go", x)
        yield
        x +=1

# instantiate some tasks in a queue
tasks = deque([countdown(10),
               countdown(5),
               countup(20)
               ])

# run a little scheduler
while tasks:
    t = tasks.pop()  # get a task
    try:
        next(t)   # run it until it yields
        tasks.appendleft(t) # reschedule
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Here is the output:

```
T-minus 5
T-minus 10
T-minus 4
T-minus 9
T-minus 3
T-minus 8
T-minus 2
T-minus 7
T-minus 1
T-minus 6
T-minus 5
T-minus 4
T-minus 3
T-minus 2
T-minus 1
```

The question is how is concurrency introduced by generators and how is it manifesting?

Comment: The concurrency is plain as day (to me) in that example. Perhaps the issue is with your understanding of the term concurrency?

Comment: Please explain Concurrency in layman's terms so i and others like me can better understand. I see this as one task after the other as they are removed and then put back into the queue

Comment: If you haven't already, you could try the PyCon talk that these slides are from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit of code implements the concept of "green threads", cooperative, userland (as opposed to Preemptive, kernel) threading.

The "threads" are the generators, each function with `yeild` or `yield from` in it.  The scheduler lives, obviously, inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` bit.

So, lets imagine we have not generators but regular lists, and each list has in it, a sequence of functions.

```
def doThis(): pass
def sayThis(): pass
def doThat(): pass
...

myThread = [doThis, doThat, doAnother]
yourThread = [sayThis, sayThat, sayAnother]
```

We could run all of the functions in order:

```
for thread in [myThread, yourThread]:
    for stmt in thread:
        stmt()
```

Or we could do them in some other order:

```
for myStmt, yourStmt in zip(myThread, yourThread):
    myStmt()
    yourStmt()
```

In the first "scheduler", we exhaust the first thread, and then proceed to the second thread.  In the second scheduler, we interleave statements out of both threads, first mine, then yours, then back to mine.

It's because we are interleaving "statements" across multiple "threads" before exausting those threads that we can say that the second scheduler gives concurrency.

Note that concurrency doesn't neccesarily mean parallelism.  It's not simultaneous execution, just overlapping.

Comment: Just as another question. If generators can help with concurrency, are threads really needed? If yes, why? if not, why not? Thanks a lot

Comment: Many things in programming are not strictly neccessary, for example: [variables](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus),  but they are convenient, so we keep them around anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to clarify:

```py
from collections import deque

def coro1():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        yield i

def coro2():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        yield i*10

print('Async behaviour'.center(60, '#'))
tasks = deque()
tasks.extend([coro1(), coro2()])

while tasks:
    task = tasks.popleft()  # select and remove a task (coro1/coro2).
    try:
        print(next(task))
        tasks.append(task)  # add the removed task (coro1/coro2) for permutation.
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Out:

```
######################Async behaviour#######################
1
10
2
20
3
30
4
40
5
50
6
60
7
70
8
80
9
90
```